# Why is an implicit conversion operator to double preferred over a conversion to std::string?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

If I define multiple conversion operators for my class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Widget {
public:
    operator double() {
        return 42.1;
    }

    operator std::string() {
        return "string";
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Widget w;
    std::cout << w << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the output of this is `42.1` even if I change the order of the member functions.

Why does the compiler always use `operator double()` instead of `operator std::string()`? What is the function resolve rules for this?

If I define the second conversion operator to `int` instead of `std::string`, the compiler will complain about an ambiguous call.

Comment: generally speaking, conversion to non-class type is preferred to conversion to class type

Comment: @InternetAussie Evidently, there is some rule that establishes some order in this case (or the compiler thinks so at least) and the question is what standard rule applies.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Ah, okay. I see.

Comment: My guess would be that it is because the streaming operators for strings are templated and the non-templated one for doubles are preferred.